Filling with points to inside of shapefile using ArcMap
I have a shapefile and I have to fill with dots or points inside of my shapefile.
Is that possible in ArcMap?

Input value is total point number.
Eventually each point should have latitude and longitude value.



Of course it's possible. There are even many ways to accomplish it (of course). But this is several tasks. 1) Generate points 2) Intersect points with feature 3) Add coordinates to attribute table. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? The best fitting points would be packed by centroids of hexagons. Your image shows centers of squares. To start, you need to choose between GenerateFishnet, GenerateTessellation, and doing the math manually in ArcPy.

Note that "filling" with a regular pattern in decimal degrees means the points will not be equidistant.

Follow the below workflow to achieve the desired output:

Use the Create Random Points GP tool available in ArcMap /
ArcGIS Pro
Use the Polygon as the AOI for the tool and also define the number of points



Create two new fields names Lat / Long with floating points (Float
or Double)



Right click over the field and use calculate geometry to get the
respective X and Y values.


Note:

Above images are from ArcGIS Pro, but you can follow the same for
ArcMap
Output points are circular in shape, use symbology to get    square
shaped features.


The Question doesn't indicate that random points are desired
